# BATCH: String substitution sub

Tags: string, batch-file, substitution

I'm trying to make a sub in batch that find a string in a string and replace it with a third one.
Searching around, I found [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Remove) that I can erase a string with the `SET` command.

So, here's what I tried:

```
:modifyString what with [in]
SET _what=%~1
ECHO "%_what%"
SET "_with=%~2
ECHO "%toWith%"
SET _In=%~3
ECHO "%_In%"
SET _In=%_In:%toWhat%=%toWith%%
ECHO %_In%
SET "%~3=%_In%"
EXIT /B
```

The `ECHO`s are there only for "debugging" purposes.

What I know is that the error is in...

```
SET _In=%_In:%toWhat%=%toWith%%
```

...because of the % character that close the `%_in%` variable.

I tried also things such as...

```
SET _In=%_In:!toWhat!=!toWith!%
SET _In=!_In:%toWhat%=%toWith%!
```

...and others without sense.

This is the main problem, the other is to return `%_In%` in `[in]`.

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using the `!` DelayedExpansion method.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "xxString=All your base are belong to us"
set "xxSubString=your base are belong"
set "xxNewSubString=of your bases belong"
echo Before
set xx
echo.
set "xxString=!xxString:%xxSubString%=%xxNewSubString%!"
echo After
set xx
endlocal
pause >nul
```

Output

```
Before
xxNewSubString=of your bases belong
xxString=All your base are belong to us
xxSubString=your base are belong

After
xxNewSubString=of your bases belong
xxString=All of your bases belong to us
xxSubString=your base are belong
```

Fixed Yours

```
@echo off
:: Make sure that you have delayed expansion enabled.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:modifyString what with [in]
SET "_what=%~1"
SET "_with=%~2"
SET "_In=%~3"
ECHO "%_what%"
ECHO "%_with%"
ECHO "%_In%"
:: The variable names were not the same as the ones
:: defined above.
SET _In=!_In:%_what%=%_with%!
ECHO %_In%

:: This will not change the value of the 3rd parameter
:: but instead will create a new parameter with the
:: value of %3 as the variable name.
SET "%~3=%_In%"
endlocal
EXIT /B
```

How to do the substring replacement without delayed expansion.  Use the `call` command to create two levels of variable expansion. Use single `%` around variables to expand first and double `%%` around variables to expand second.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "xxString=All your base are belong to us"
set "xxSubString=your base are belong"
set "xxNewSubString=of your bases belong"
echo Before
set xx
echo.
call set "xxString=%%xxString:%xxSubString%=%xxNewSubString%%%"
echo After
set xx
endlocal
pause >nul
```

Comment: I wonder a thing or two...
Why the `SET xx`?
How can I return the value if I put this in a label?

Comment: The `set xx` is just displaying all of the variables that start with the letters `xx` to the screen.  It is easier than echo each of them individually.  `endlocal` is only ending the scope of the `setlocal`.  You can still use `goto :eof` or `exit /b`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all guys!

I paste you what I finally made:

```
:modifyString what with in tRtn
set "_in=%~3"
set "_in=!_in:%~1=%~2!"
IF NOT "%~4" == "" SET %~4=%_in%
EXIT /B
```

E.G. If I call this sub in this way:

```
SET "str=All your base are belong to us"
SET "toFind=your base are belong"
SET "space=of your bases belong"
ECHO %str%
CALL :modifyString "%toFind%" "%space%" "%str%" string
```

%string% would became the new corrected string, so if you do...

```
ECHO "%string%"
```

it would print:

```
"All of your bases belong to us"
```

P.S. I'm sorry if I'm late, but because of my low reputation i had to wait!